# ContextMenu on disabled controls such as buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking for a way to enable/disable buttons using their`ContextMenu`. But my problem is when I click on the Enable `MenuItem` to disable the button the `ContextMenu` won't show anymore.

Is there a way to keep the `ContextMenu` or other behavior on a disabled Control?

```
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
cm.MenuItems.Add("Enable", new EventHandler(enableButton));

this.button1.ContextMenu = cm;



private void enableButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    if (menuItem != null)
    {
        ContextMenu menu = menuItem.GetContextMenu();
        Control sourceControl = menu.SourceControl;
        sourceControl.Enabled = !sourceControl.Enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make your own disabling functionality, set the buttons to grayed out, intercept their events, this way the button will appear disabled but be enabled to receive the ContextMenu event. This behaviour is "By-Design"

Comment: Even if it was possible, it would be a bad design as not one would ever try to right click on a disable control. The only case where it might somewhat make sense would be a UI designer.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx)

> With the Enabled property, you can enable or disable controls at run
>   time. For example, you can disable controls that do not apply to the
>   current state of the application. You can also disable a control to
>   restrict its use. For example, a button can be disabled to prevent the
>   user from clicking it. If a control is disabled, it cannot be
>   selected.

and

> When a container control has its enabled property set to false, all
>   its contained controls are disabled, as well. For example, if the user
>   clicks on any of the controls contained in a disabled GroupBox
>   control, no events are raised.

So, disabled control cannot raise any events.

You can make your own disable method which make button gayed and disable click events, and reverse enable method.

Based on @esiprogrammer sugestion you can do something like this:

```
private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        Point pt = e.Location;

        Control ctrl = this.GetChildAtPoint(pt);

        if (ctrl != null)
        {
            ContextMenu menu = ctrl.ContextMenu;              

            menu.Show(ctrl, new Point(10,10));
        }                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your own disabling functionality, set the buttons to grayed out, intercept their events, this way the button will appear disabled but be enabled to receive the ContextMenu event. This behaviour is "By-Design".

You can easily work out the btn.Font to look disabled. For the events one way is to unsubscribe them on Disable, and Hook them up on Enable, here is an example on getting a controls events...

```
dynamic controltype = btn;
var events = Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType(controltype.AssemblyQualifiedName, false, true).GetEvents();
foreach (var item in events)
{
  //EventHandler<T> use a generic Event Handler to Subscribe and Unsubscribe
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried doing this `dynamic controltype = new Button();` and got an error on the next line: Additional information: 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' does not contain a definition for 'AssemblyQualifiedName'

Answer (score 1):

there is a workaround to detect right click on mouse up event of form and show context menu. and using `this.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location)` you can find which control you right clicked on.

```
private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right
          && this.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location)?.Name == "enableButton")
     {
        ContextMenu.Show();
     }
 }
```

Comment: But this is if you click on a form, it doesn't specify the control you clicked on? So if there is multiple ContextMenu's this wont work.

Comment: it's possible to find the control using `GetChildAtPoint` . but I agree it's not a clean solution